# XML/XSLT - xsl:key concat

Tags: xml, xslt, concatenation, xslkey

I have the following **XML** code:

```
<training_center>
<course id="XML">
    <title>Course 1</title>
    <keywords>
        <keyword>XML</keyword>
        <keyword>XPath</keyword>
    </keywords>
    <teachers>
        <teacher>Nikitin</teacher>
        <teacher>Pavlov</teacher>
    </teachers>
</course>
<course id="AJAX">
    <title>Course 2</title>
    <keywords>
        <keyword>AJAX</keyword>
        <keyword>XML</keyword>
    </keywords>
    <teachers>
        <teacher>Nikitin</teacher>
        <teacher>Chebykin</teacher>
    </teachers>
</course>
</training_center>
```

And the following **XSL** code:

```
<xsl:key 
    name='concat_key'
    match="/training_center/course"
    use="concat(teachers/teacher, ':', keywords/keyword)"
/>
<xsl:template match="/">                
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('concat_key', concat('Nikitin',':','XML'))" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="course">
    <xsl:element name="course">         
        <xsl:value-of select="./title" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

After **XSL-transformation** *Course 1* is shown only. But logically *Course 2* shall be shown also. 
In what error?

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I am assuming you are using XSLT 1.0, because ... [an educated guess based on your result].*

First, the reason why your method cannot work is that the `concat()` function works on *string-values*, not *node-sets*.

```
concat(teacher, ':', keyword)
```

is evaluated as:

```
concat(string(teacher), ':', string(keyword))
```

and (in XSLT 1.0) `string(node-set)` returns the string-value of the **first** node in the set.

There are other methods you can use to achieve your goal, for example:

**1. Use a key with a predicate:**

```
<xsl:key name="course-by-teacher" match="course" use="teachers/teacher" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('course-by-teacher', Nikitin')[keywords/keyword='XML']" />
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="course">
    <course>         
        <xsl:value-of select="title" />
    </course>
</xsl:template>
```

**2. Use the intersection of two keys:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"
extension-element-prefixes="set">
<xsl:output method='xml' version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' indent='yes'/>

<xsl:key name="course-by-teacher" match="course" use="teachers/teacher" />
<xsl:key name="course-by-keyword" match="course" use="keywords/keyword" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="set:intersection(key('course-by-teacher', 'Nikitin'), key('course-by-keyword', 'XML'))" />
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="course">
    <course>         
        <xsl:value-of select="title" />
    </course>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this method requires the EXSLT `set:intersection()` function which is supported by many XSLT 1.0 processors - but not all of them. If necessary, I will post a (more complex) method that can produce the intersection of two node-sets natively in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, send please. In *XSLT 2.0* my goal will be achieved?

Comment: Why don't you read about it at the source: http://books.google.com/books?id=Xw3_tzEJVEwC&pg=PA237&lpg=PA237&dq=xpath+2.0+intersect&source=bl&ots=03ToDMmtbI&sig=2lkuI4eV_UDOcHm6hRdfJpIyCo0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=M7MHU90Xo4rsBu7YgcgK&ved=0CHAQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=xpath%202.0%20intersect&f=false It also discusses XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

concat(teachers/teacher, ':', keywords/keyword) will concat first teachers/teacher, ':', and first keywrods/keyword for every training_center/course. But in your second "course" AJAX is the first "keyword".

Comment: Is your requirement to select "course"s that contain teacher = "Nikitin" and keyword="XML"?

Comment: Yes, and desirably using `concat` xsl:key